# Non autonomous lipschitz condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I can show that the two solutions satisfy the IVP. To show that this does not contradict the existence and uniqueness theorem I am trying to show that the function is not  lipschitz.

So: $\displaystyle\frac{|f(s,u)-f(s,v)|}{|u-v|}= \displaystyle\frac{|s||u^{1/2}-v^{1/2}|}{|u-v|}$

I am required to show this is $\nleq K$.

Comment: And there are lots of other solutions, namely, every function $y$ such that, for some $x_0\geqslant0$, $y(x)=0$ for every $x\leqslant x_0$ and $y(x)=\frac1{16}(x-x_0)^4$ for every $x\gt x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$|u-v|=|u^{1/2} + v^{1/2}||u^{1/2} - v^{1/2}|$$

So the difference cancels; why does this make the ratio unbounded?

Comment: Apolgies I'd made it that far, I was stuck on the next step.

Comment: If $u$ and $v$ are near $0$ then $1/(u^{1/2}+v^{1/2})$ is large.

Comment: I understand this, I'm just confused as to what conclusions I can draw. Is this saying that $x\sqrt$is not lipschitz when $y=0$?